# MySQL how to recover data from an old disk?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Is it possible that I can recover data from mySQL ubuntu server? I needed to change a disk in my server so I installed a new ubuntu, but in my old disk I still have files in /var/lib/mysql/ where my old databases are. Is it possible to recover a database from files? How to do it? Just copying database from old disk /var/lib/mysql/ to a new server disk? Will it work instantly or I need to create first empty databases in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Copy your whole data directory (overwriting your new installation), assuming it is using the same or a newer mysql version. If you have already data in your new server and want to preserve it, make a backup first (or do this on a different server/laptop), make a mysqldump with the old restored database, restore the new database and import the dump into the new server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is still here it´s promising for your recovery.

1/. You need to back up this /var/lib/mysql directory

```
sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.back
```

2/. Reinstall completely mysql (it will erase the mysql folder)

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

3/. Erase the new data folder with your old one

```
sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql.bask /var/lib/mysql
```

If you´re using exactly same directories it should work like that.

Comment: Thnak you ;) But is it possible that I just copy one folder with a database? I dont need more ;) and I still want to use a new one databases

Comment: @Anna K The problem is: you need your mysql configuration files matching your database list (files: ib..). If you just integrate the database file you will have an error when checking the content. The best you can do is integrating this old configuration files and after that declare your new database